# Problems when adding Eureka to JHipster monolithic application

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I have a simple JHipster monolithic application that I would like to connect to an existing Eureka discovery service and see what services are running.

However, if I add eureka to the pom.xml, I get NullPointerException in the AbstractRememberMeServices.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.AbstractRememberMeServices.autoLogin(AbstractRememberMeServices.java:118)
```

Debugging, it looks like this service is not configured as most properties are null.

The following warning appears in the logs, which I guess is the problem:

```
WARN 45015 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor  :
  Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definition 'refreshScope' since its 
  singleton instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a 
  non-static @Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor 
  return type: Consider declaring such methods as 'static'.
```

I've included eureka as follows (as used in the JHipster microservice apps):

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Camden.SR6</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I'm using JHipster 4.1.1 and Spring Boot 1.5.2.RELEASE

Does anyone know of a fix or workaround for this?

Comment: This is now an officially supported option ! Generate a new app with both JWT and Hazelcast and you will have the option to use the JHipster Registry with it. Sorry this is not well documented at the moment.

Comment: What if we want to use a vanilla eureka server instead of the jhipster registry?  I am having the exact same problem as above.  Maybe this deserves a bug report?

Comment: @PierreBesson is this only supported with jwt and hazelcast?  We currently use spring security and ehcache.